# Android Collapsing Layout with parallax effect for fragments crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my MainActivity.java in the onCreate() I have this:

```
collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(true);
```

It works for one two times donw and upscrolling and than it stops everything - and when you scroll up till the imageview is not visible, the hamburger and the meatball icons are not visible anymore; they also scroll with the rest upwards.

I get this error message:

> W/Adreno-GSL: :
>   sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
>   E/Adreno-GSL: : GSL MEM ERROR:
>   kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.

Everything gets black and nothig works.

I have tried to implement this [code](https://github.com/OliWheeler/CheeseSquareFragment)

This is my app_bar_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.choix.crowdselfie.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorCrowdSelfieYellow"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/earth"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorCrowdSelfieGreen" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35876952/3037960)